# Skip user validation if the user is resetting their password in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise

**Backstory**

We are currently working with a vanilla Devise setup. No significant modifications.

**What happened:**

User validations have been changed.

**How we are migrating user profiles:**

Currently when a user logs in, and their records isn't valid, we force them to update their profile.

**Problem:**

Users who are resetting their password (because they don't know it), are unable to, because their profile is invalid, due to the new changes.

**Goal:**

Skip a validation, if only resetting their password?

Comment: Have you tried skip(:validate => false) or else refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations. Can you paste your code?

Comment: Actually that would probably work. Just overwrite the devise controller on password reset. I'm not sure where the action is, might have to do a little digging.